# Passing a property into a method to change that property

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, lambda, properties

Not sure if this is possible, but here is what I am trying to do:

I want to have a dictionary that contains a mapping of a column index to a property name used to populate that index.

In my code I will loop through an array if strings and use the dictionary to look up which column it should map to.

My end result code would look like:

```
for(int index = 0; index < fields.Length)
{
    fieldPropertyMapping[index] = StripQuotes(fields[index]);
}
```

Comment: BTW, I know I can do this:
var mapping = new Dictionary<int, Action<myType>>
{
   { 0, t => t.myProperty = StripQuotes(fields[0])  }
}

But I don't like that solution

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you don't like that solution?

Comment: I don't want to put the functionality inside of the map, just the concept of "this is the property to operate on for this index".  The logic of how to get the field value would be repeated in each dictionary entry with the example I gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you're asking specifically, you'll have to use reflection (as you tagged your question) to do this. Have a look at the `PropertyInfo` class. I'm not entirely certain what your code is doing, but a general example of reflectively setting a property value would be:

```
object targetInstance = ...; // your target instance

PropertyInfo prop = targetInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

prop.SetValue(targetInstance, null, newValue);
```

You could, however, pass an `Action<T>` instead, if you know the property at some point in the code. For example:

```
YourType targetInstance = ...;

Action<PropertyType> prop = value => targetInstance.PropertyName = value;

... // in your consuming code

prop(newValue);
```

Or, if you know the type when you call it but you don't have the instance, you could make it an `Action<YourType, PropertyType>`. This also would prevent creating a closure.

```
Action<YourType, PropertyType> prop = (instance, value) => instance.PropertyName = value;

... // in your consuming code

prop(instance, newValue);
```

To make this fully generic ("generic" as in "non-specific", not as in generics), you'll probably have to make it an `Action<object>` and cast it to the proper property type within the lambda, but this should work either way.

Comment: Your second example was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  I was dancing all around that solution, but couldn't get it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Use reflection. Store and pass a `PropertyInfo` object into the method and set it's value through reflection.
2. Create an ActionDelegate with a closure to that property and pass that into the method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflection to get the properties for a class:

```
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
  //read / write the property, here... do whatever you need
}
```